# OR operation on binary strings in c giving half output as wrong

Tags: c, string, binary, binary-operators, or-operator

```
int stringXor(char *str1,char *str2)
{
    int num1=0,num2=0;
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(str1); i++)
    {
        num1=str1[i]-'0';
        num2=str2[i]-'0';
        num1 = num1 | num2;
        str1[i]=(char)num1;
        //printf("%d",str1[i]);
    }

    int count=0;
    for(int j=0;j<strlen(str1);j++)
    {
        if(str1[j]==1)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I don't know what the error is, but `or` operation is not successful on each char of the string.

Comment: I suppose you want `num1 = (num1 | num2) + '0';`

Comment: Please clarify. What is the exact input you're providing, the output you're getting and the output you're expecting?

Comment: @Lashane i need to calculate or of 2 strings str1 and str2 and save it to the str1. NO it is not working!

Comment: @BobKaufman i am providing 2 binary strings say 10010 and 10110 of same length and after calculating or operation i am counting number of 1's in the resulting string. and then i return the count. While the output i am getting is sometimes correct n sometimes garbage value in or operatins.

Comment: also change `if (str1[j] == '1')`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but using `strlen` in the end condition in `for (int i = 0; i<strlen(str1); i++)` is very ineffective.

Comment: Please show an example of expected output for a given input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function that will return the number of positions that contain a `1` in either string, consider writing a simpler function that does just that. For example:

```
int CountOnes( char *str1, char *str2 )
{
    int count = 0;
    int len = strlen( str1 );  // we assume that strlen(str1) == strlen(str2)

    for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        if ( str1[ i ] == '1' || str2[ i ] == '1' )
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Note that this function will not include the side effect of changing `str1` as yours currently does.

To store the resulting OR'd string to `str1`, change the line

```
if ( str1[ i ] == '1' || str2[ i ] == '1' )
```

to

```
str1[ i ] = ( ( str1[ i ] - '0' ) | ( str2[ i ] - '0' ) ) + '0';
if ( str1[ i ] == '1' )
    count++;
```